# Replacing a refrigerator compressor fan motor with one with different electrical values (GE side-by-side TPG21JRDAWW)

Tags: refrigerator, fans, replacement, compressor

I have rewired very basic motorcycle electrical systems before, but have no understanding of electrical values other than "don't mix 110 and 220V", and "don't put a 6V bulb on a 12V vehicle" :D

I have a 20+ year-old side-by-side GE refrigerator (TPG21JRDAWW) whose compressor fan motor is acting up, i.e. the fan only spins intermittently, and as a consequence the compressor is on most of the time.

The original fan motor is part #WR60X0266 (it also says 5SME44AG3900A), and has long been discontinued.

The electrical values of the fan are:

- 220V
- 50/60Hz
- .12A
- 2.9W
- 1100RPM

By researching cross references of parts numbers and their replacements, I found a different (affordable) fan for GE units with similar mounting points, and similar values, except for the 2 last ones:
2W (instead of the original 2.9W), and
1300RPM (instead of the original 1100)

I'm guessing the "W" values are the most critical, but I'm not sure whether the 2W/2.9W values refer to max output, or consumption.

My question is: is there any risk or critical downside to installing this motor on the refrigerator?

Here are some pics of the OEM fan and the candidate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: While replacing the motor is definitely less expensive than replacing a whole fridge, bear in mind that modern fridges are more efficient than 20 year old ones, especially if the doors don't seal all that well.

Comment: @jsotola; thanks, that was sorted out on the fly.

Comment: @FreeMan: No doubt, but this would be an expensive fridge to replace, and it works beautifully apart for the coil cooling issue. Seals are all in great shape as well.

Comment: W is watts.  Watts is how power it uses, so it uses less power than the old one.  Hopefully from better efficiently and should be better for your wallet.

Comment: Watts *on this type of device* is pretty much a non-issue. 2W, 3W, even 10W - won't make much difference. But the *speed* may matter a lot. Does 1300 RPM vs. 1100 RPM matter? Maybe. Maybe not. An appliance or refrigeration expert *might* know.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was hoping that the Watts value was indeed for power drawn rather than max acceptable power: pheww! Regarding the speed, it may matter more than I suspect, but it seems like a lower value than original would be more of an issue than higher. The fan cools down the coils which transform hot gas to cold; so a higher airflow sounds like a better option if strictly identical isn't available..

Comment: Are the first two photos of different fans?

Comment: @Huesmann: The first is of the unit on my fridge, with the specs nice and visible. I added the second (found on the net) to show the size on the fan. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Zooky because you mention two fans but picture three.

Comment: @Huesmann: Oh, ok. I'd mentioned that the pics were of the OEM motor and the candidate. The third is of the potential replacement part.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned   W for Watts is the power consumption is a non-issue. The new one uses less power. And it spins faster. But what is more important is the volume of air moved. And you dont have values for either fan.

It won't do any damage. But it may still not be adequate. It shouldn't be far off, so give it a try.

Comment: You're right, I don't have values for airflows, but I found the potential replacement unit by cross-referencing GE fan motors, and going down the list of replacement references. There's no guarantee GE kept the same fan size, weight, and blade inclinations throughout the # changes, but I'm hoping they didn't bother changing those. In any case, if the speed is a little off but the unit doesn't damage the fridge, that'll be better than having the compressor do all the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

So I received the slightly different spec fan motor, and did some checking.
The plug and wiring were different: the old unit had only 2 wires: a red and a black one, matching 2 coming from the fridge. The new had 3: 2 black, and one green meant to be screwed to the chassis (so I assume a ground?). I connected the red wire (fridge) with the plain black wire (fan), the black wire (fridge) with the black wire with writing (fan), and discarded the green wire.

The spindle started spinning as soon as I plugged the connector, so that tells me the motor *was* at fault, and that I connected the right wires. I checked that the fan still spun in the same direction (it did), but it seems I'd installed the fan the other way around the last time I'd changed it: it said something like "nut this side" on the fan rotor, which was on the wrong side of the nut when I unmounted the fan.

Other thing I noticed: the fan sucks air *away* from the coils and the compressor, rather than blowing *towards* them: the opposite of what I expected.   But the air circulating around certainly makes the whole area cool. I can feel air drawn from the grill on the front of the fridge, and cool air blown on the side (it's backed against a wall).
It's been installed for a few hours now, and it seems to be working as it should. The compressor kept functioning for a while, and at one point both the compressor and the fan turned off for about 10 minutes. Then only the fan turned back on, and it's been humming ever since. It's much more silent than when the compressor was on all the time, and the temps are good. I'll obviously keep an eye and an ear on the cycles and the temps, but it seems like it's going well.

For future reference, or anyone searching the net with the same issue, the # of the new unit is 5KSM81FFL0074.